# MacOS SwiftUI strange behavior opening sidebar

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui, sidebar

As can be seen from the image when opening the side menu to a strange behavior it seems.

Can you tell me how to solve the problem?

[image]

ContentView

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }.navigationTitle("Explore")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

projectSchemaApp

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct projectSchemaApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SidebarView()
                .frame(minWidth: 600, minHeight: 600)
        }
    }
}
```

SidebarView

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SidebarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Simboli SF")
                Group{
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                        Label("Tutti", systemImage: "message")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                        Label("Novità", systemImage: "cloud.sun")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                        Label("Multicolore", systemImage: "bolt.car")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                        Label("Comunicazione", systemImage: "pills")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                        Label("Meteo", systemImage: "ticket")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                        Label("Oggetti e strumenti", systemImage: "function")
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                Text("Libreria")
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                    Label("Simboli personalizzati", systemImage: "option")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Explore")
            .frame(minWidth: 10, maxWidth: 200)
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction){
                    Button(action: toggleSidebar, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "sidebar.left")
                    })
                }
            }
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

func toggleSidebar() {
        NSApp.keyWindow?.firstResponder?.tryToPerform(#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil)
}

struct SidebarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SidebarView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, *hacky* activation - *strange* behavior... )) If I correctly understood your concern I'd recommend to disable button for the time of animation. But it is always better to provide explicit description of what's bad for you and what you expect instead.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour

Comment: @Asperi: I hadn't actually noticed the button's weird behavior.
I was talking about the weird behavior when opening the sidebar.

Comment: @Asperi: I'm a big fan of yours, I also follow your `Demo` project I can ask you if you could create an example of a simple structure with a side menu that when you click on a `NavigationLink` the `ContentView` changes.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: There are only three files so it shouldn't be difficult.
What mistake does it give you?

Comment: Mistakes? It works fine using the exact same code you have posted and I can’t reproduce the issue.

Comment: I don't see it with your example, but I see it in one of my own projects. Not sure why...